# How do I lookup Facebook ad parameters given fbclid?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am currently tracking ad performance on Facebook and have come across the 62-alphanumeric-character Facebook click ID (fbclid) in most of the visitor URLs. Sometimes, because of the way the ads are set, the ad ID (which is needed for reporting on click performance) is not included in the UTM parameters of the visitor URL. In those cases, it would be helpful to lookup the 18-digit ad ID associated with just the fbclid of the visitor.

e.g. If we know a visitor clicked the following URL, can we get the associated ad ID?

```
www.example.com?fbclid=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

The Conversions API looked promising to me, but to my knowledge, it only offers POST requests to associate performance metrics to specified fbclids. What I would like instead is a way to send GET requests to obtain the ad_id of a known fbclid.

Answer (score 3):

No they hide that, they don't tell you what what click id points to (ad, or organic post) . I believe all you can do is upload it as a custom conversion to ads manager and Facebook will attribute it properly AKA it will show up as a conversion within the ads manager